# perception_pcl on RPI2

Tags: ros, perception-pcl, ros-indigo, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've been developing a cheap scanning LIDAR unit, that I'm trying to integrate on a custom robot that uses a RPI2 running ROS Indigo as its controller. I developed the hardware on a PC running Ubuntu. Now that I want to integrate it, I'm finding that I cannot build the perception_pcl packages, due to a dependency with PCL. The RPI2 is running Raspbian Jessie. Perception_pcl lists libpcl-all and libpcl-all-dev as dependencies. The closest matching packages in the Raspbian repo is libpcl1.7 and libpcl1.7-dev.

Would editing the perception_pcl source to depend on libpcl1.7 & libpcl1.7-dev fix the issue? Otherwise, where would I find the source for libpcl-all & libpcl-all-dev?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221289/perception_pcl-on-rpi2/) by [ben.gill](https://answers.ros.org/users/24889/ben.gill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the pcl source can be found on their github: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.

I don't know anything about Raspbian, but here is a page that lists information for all the Linux distros that have binaries: http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html, maybe the binaries for Debian will work???

Lastly, the pcl mailing list is pretty active: http://www.pcl-users.org/

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0